# Every $R$-module is injective implies $R$ has the descending chain condition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose that every R-module is injective.

There are a few definitions of injective that we can go by:

1. E is an injective R-module if and only if Hom$_R(−, E)$ is an exact functor.
2. An R-module E is injective if for all R-module homomorphisms $\phi : M \longrightarrow N$ and $ψ : M \longrightarrow E$ where $\phi$ is injective, there exists an R-linear homomorphism $θ : N \longrightarrow E$ such that $θ ◦ ϕ = ψ$

I tend to see definition 1 most often.

We want to prove two things:

1. $R$ has the descending chain condition (DCC).  That is, Let $M$ be an $R$-module.  Then for every descending chain $N_1>N_2>...$ of submodules of $M$, there exists $k\geq 1$ such that $N_i=N_k$ for all $i\geq k$.

This is also equivalent to proving $R$ is an Artinian ring, correct?

2. $R$ is a finite direct sum of left ideals.

Here is the start to my proof:

Suppose every $R$-module is injective.  Let $M$ be an $R$-module and suppose we have the descending chain $N_1>N_2>...$ of submodules of $M$.

Now I had an idea of applying the functor Hom$_R(−, M)$ to get the following surjections:

Hom$_R(N_1,M)\longrightarrow$ Hom$_R(N_2,M)\longrightarrow ...$

And then somehow getting an isomorphsim for large enough $i>0$ where Hom$_R(N_i,M)$ is isomorphic to Hom$_R(N_{i+1},M)$

I dont't know if this is even on the right track.  I'm not sure how to use injectivity to get what we want.

And I don't know how to prove 2 either. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A ring $R$ being Artinian (satisfying the DCC) doesn't mean that *every* $R$-module $M$ satisfies the DCC on submodules (there's no non-zero ring for which that's true), but that $R$, considered as a module for itself, satisfies the DCC.

Answer (score 3):

If every module is injective then every short exact sequence of modules splits and therefore all modules are projective. It follows that all modules are semisimple ---every submodule is a direct summand--- so the ring is a (left) semisimple ring. Such a ring is artinian and noetherian: this is shown in every textbook on the subject.

Comment: What about the last part? How do we know $R$ is a finite direct sum of left ideals?

Comment: Since the ring is artinianit contains minimal ideals, and since it is semisimple it is the direct sum of them. that's also a standard fact about semisimple rings.

Comment: And finally, why does being a semisimple ring imply $R$ is artinian? That's a theorem? I apologize, I'm new to this material.

Comment: Yes. I suggest you look into Lam's book on modules and rings, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled this question upon when working on Exercise 5 in Section 18.2 of Dummit and Foote. Presumably the OP was working on the exact same exercise.

Mariano has provided an answer already, but it would not have been possible for Mariano to know that the content in his answer is yet to be proven at this point in Dummit and Foote. Indeed, the whole purpose of this exercise to get the reader to prove this implication:
$$ \text{Every (left) } R\text{-module} \text{ is injective} \implies R \text{ is Artinian}$$

Since this question evidently receives a steady trickle of views, I thought I may as well write down what I managed to eventually come up with in case it's useful for people in the future. And if I made a mistake, then please leave a comment!

---

Suppose, for contradiction that $R$ is not Artinian. Then there exist left ideals $I_i \subset R$ (with $i \in \mathbb N$) such that

$$ R = I_0 \supsetneq I_1 \supsetneq I_2 \supsetneq I_3 \supsetneq \dots $$

For each $i \in \mathbb N$, we have a short exact sequence of left $R$-modules
$$ 0 \to I_{i+1} \to I_i \to I_i/I_{i+1} \to 0.$$
$I_{i+1}$ is an *injective* left $R$-module by assumption. Therefore, the above short exact sequence *splits* - which is to say that there exists a complementary ideal $J_i \subset R$ such that
$$ I_i = I_{i+1} \oplus J_i.$$
The fact that $I_{i+1} \neq I_i$ implies that $J_i$ is not the zero ideal.

Now consider the ideal $J$ consisting of finite sums of elements from the $J_i$'s. It's not too hard to see that any element of $J$ can be decomposed into a finite sum of elements from the $J_i$'s in only one way. Therefore, $J$ is a *direct* sum:
$$J = \oplus_{i\in \mathbb N} J_i.$$

We have the short exact sequence of left $R$-modules
$$ 0 \to J \to R \to R/J \to 0,$$
and since $J$ is an injective left $R$-module by assumption, this short exact sequence splits. So there exists a complementary ideal $K$ such that
$$ R = J \oplus K.$$
(K may or may not be the zero ideal.)

Thus we have
$$ R = \left( \oplus_{i \in \mathbb N}J_i \right) \oplus K,$$
and none of the $J_i$'s are the zero ideal.

Now consider the element $1 \in R$. By virtue of the above direct sum decomposition, we can write
$$ 1 = j_{1} + j_{2} + \dots + j_{n} + k,$$
where $j_{i} \in J_{p_i}$ for some $p_i \in \mathbb N$ and $k \in K$.

Now pick any element $j' \in J_{l}$, where $l \notin \{ p_1, p_2, \dots , p_n \}$.

We have
$$ j' = j'.1 = j'j_{1} + j'j_{2} + \dots + j'j_n + j'k.$$
Thus $j'$ is in $J_l \cap (J_{p_1} \oplus J_{p_2} \oplus \dots \oplus J_{n} \oplus K)$. So $j' = 0$. Since $j'$ was an arbitrary element of $J_l$, we find that $J_l$ is the zero ideal, which is a contradiction.